# Shiny updating whilst function is running?

Tags: r, shiny

On clicking "Start Ramp", I am expecting the display to update with the new counter value every time add.to.counter(ticks_per_second) is run in the for loop, but the update only happens at the end of the for loop. Is this because the main ramp function is still executing? How could I make this update such that it updates on each change of the counter value - whilst that main function is still running?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start Ramp")
    ),

    mainPanel(
    tags$b("Simple counter using reactiveValues() - An example"),
    br(),
    actionButton("add1", "+ 1"),
    actionButton("sub1", "- 1"),
    actionButton("reset", "set to 0"),
    br(),
    textOutput("count")
    )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # Defining & initializing the reactiveValues object

  add.to.counter <- function(val) {
    counter$countervalue <<- counter$countervalue + val 
  }

  ramp <- function(length_of_ramp, ticks_per_second) {
    # length of ramp in seconds
    # ticks: divide each second into this number of ticks

    ticks <- length_of_ramp*ticks_per_second

    for (n in 1:ticks) {
      shinyjs::delay(ticks_per_second*1000, add.to.counter(ticks_per_second))
    }

  }

  observeEvent(input$start, { ramp(length_of_ramp = 10, ticks_per_second = 1) }
  )

    observeEvent(input$add1, {
      counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it
    })
    observeEvent(input$sub1, {
      counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue - 1  # if the sub button is clicked, decrement the value by 1 and update it
    })
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      counter$countervalue <- 0                     # if the reset button is clicked, set the counter value to zero
    })
    output$count <- renderText({
      paste("Counter Value is ", counter$countervalue)   # print the latest value stored in the reactiveValues object
    })


}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Sys.sleep()` in

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start Ramp")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tags$b("Simple counter using reactiveValues() - An example"),
      br(),
      actionButton("add1", "+ 1"),
      actionButton("sub1", "- 1"),
      actionButton("reset", "set to 0"),
      br(),
      textOutput("count")
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  add.to.counter <- function(val) {
    counter$countervalue <<- counter$countervalue + val 
  }

  ramp <- function(length_of_ramp, ticks_per_second) {
    # length of ramp in seconds
    # ticks: divide each second into this number of ticks

    ticks <- length_of_ramp*ticks_per_second
    for (n in 1:ticks) {
      add.to.counter(ticks_per_second)
      # Sys.sleep(1/ticks_per_second)
    }
  }

  observeEvent(input$start, { ramp(length_of_ramp = 10, ticks_per_second = 1) }
  )

  counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0) # Defining & initializing the reactiveValues object

  observeEvent(input$add1, {
    counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it
  })
  observeEvent(input$sub1, {
    counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue - 1  # if the sub button is clicked, decrement the value by 1 and update it
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    counter$countervalue <- 0                     # if the reset button is clicked, set the counter value to zero
  })
  output$count <- renderText({
    paste("Counter Value is ", counter$countervalue)   # print the latest value stored in the reactiveValues object
  })


}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That is a crucial part of what I am trying to achieve, i.e that there is a specified delay, so removing it does not quite solve the problem. So, I need some other alternative to delaying the function. I will try with shinyjs:: delay

Comment: ````Sys.time()```` suspends execution of all R expressions, so ````Sys.time()```` isn't the best option in your case

Comment: Updated answer; but ShinyJS delay doesn't work as expected. Should it not add 1,000ms delay at the beginning of every iteration of the loop, thus having a counter that increments every second? Instead it pauses a second, then quickly counts up to 10.

Comment: So the issue is that the for in the new code loop keeps calling shinyjs::delay repeatedly, so it doesn't get to enact its delay at all. So how does one achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `shinyjs::delay()` only delays once even when called within a for loop. I do not know how to make `shinyjs::delay()` delay each iteration of the for loop. In fact, I suspect that this is not possible, given that `shinyjs::delay()` only works in interactive sessions or context, whereas the for loop itself is not an interactive or reactive context.

To attain what you want, I've had to have a bit of a rethink on the server code. I've made use of `invalidateLater`, `isolate`, and `reactiveValue` to get the text output to update every second *and* to calculate the counter every second such that each second, the counter is updated in the text output. Since, this will run forever unless some values are changed, I've used `if` statements to conditionally print the text output.

Full code below:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start Ramp")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tags$b("Simple counter using reactiveValues() - An example"),
      br(),
      actionButton("add1", "+ 1"),
      actionButton("sub1", "- 1"),
      actionButton("reset", "set to 0"),
      br(),
      uiOutput("count")
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  length_of_ramp = 10; ticks_per_second = 1

  ticks <- length_of_ramp*ticks_per_second

  counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0, forLoop = ticks, loopCount = Inf, finalCount = 0)

  observeEvent(input$start, {

    counter$loopCount <- -1

  })

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000)
    counter$loopCount <- isolate(counter$loopCount) + 1

    if(counter$loopCount == ticks){counter$finalCount <- counter$loopCount}
    print(counter$finalCount)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add1, {
    counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     # if the add button is clicked, increment the value by 1 and update it
  })
  observeEvent(input$sub1, {
    counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue - 1  # if the sub button is clicked, decrement the value by 1 and update it
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    counter$countervalue <- 0                     # if the reset button is clicked, set the counter value to zero
  })


  output$count <- renderUI({

    invalidateLater(millis = 1000, session)

    if(counter$loopCount < ticks){
      counter$countervalue <- isolate(counter$countervalue) + ticks_per_second
      paste("Counter Value is ", isolate(counter$countervalue))
    }else if (counter$loopCount == Inf || counter$loopCount == 0 || counter$finalCount == ticks) {
      paste("Counter Value is ", isolate(counter$countervalue))
    }
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]